# Nodejs: Middleware for only page loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working with nodejs and ejs template. I want to set a middleware which will be called only when page loading, not when I send request from code.

Example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session){
        console.log("OKAY");
    } 
    next();
});
```

I want this log appears only on page loading, not when I send request from code like below

```
$.get( "/users", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. In your middleware, you can check [req.path](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.path) to see if it's a path that you should apply the middleware to or not and use an `if` in your middlware to either just call `next()` without doing anything or to do whatever the middleware is designed to do.
2. You can design your routes to that page routes and ajax routes are on separate paths and then design a router for page routes and a router for ajax routes and put the middleware only on the page router.

It will really help you a lot (with either option above) if you design your URLs so it's easy for your server to distinguish whether this is a URL that should or should not have the middleware applied.  Usually, the simplest way to do that is to use a known prefix on one or both branches of your URL design.  For example, all ajax URLs could start with `/api` and then you can easily shunt all API calls off to a special router and all other URLs are non-API URLs (probably page URLs).

Here's an example of the separate API router:

```
// split off all API calls to a separate router
let apiRouter = express.Router();
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// handle /api/users
apiRouter.get('/users', handleUserAjaxRequest);

// handle all other /api/xxx routes that don't have their own handler
apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // if /api request not handled by here, then don't allow it to propagate further
    // it must be a invalid /api/xxx URL, so do a 404
    res.status(404).end();
});

// this won't get called if there's a /api/xxx URL because that will have
// already been handled by the apiRouter
app.use(someMiddleware);

app.get('/somepage', handleSomePageURL);
```

You could also use a separate router for all your page requests which might make modularity a little cleaner with all the API routes in one module and all the page routes in another module, each exporting their own router.

Comment: Thank you. I saw req.xhr from your link and it's better for my little nodejs project. But of course I will manage my futur big nodejs projects as you explain in the second option ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery to send request from client and I saw from jfriend00's link that [req.xhr](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.xhr) returns a Boolean property that is true if the request’s X-Requested-With header field is “XMLHttpRequest”, indicating that the request was issued by a client library such as jQuery.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.xhr){
        console.log("FROM CLIENT LIBRARY");
    } 
    next();
});
```

Thank you jfriend00

Comment: I really think it's better to just design your URLs so API urls are separate from page URLS in an easy to distinguish way.  That's a ton more extensible and controls things by actual function rather than by some flag a client might or might not set.

Comment: Yes you're right. The middleware is called many times when page loading and It's not good because I query many times into it. Thank you